# Pointers as function arguments

Tags: c++, pointers

Again, I did stumble upon some excercise in which I can't comprehend some basic lines, that said I can't really understand how some things are working. I do know pointers but sometimes it seems to me that I'm STILL lacking some basic knowlegde.

What is the point of using pointers in the following example (in function arguments and comparing string type data to char type data as it's pointed out in the function called: InsertPerson).

Let me put it this way, we've got the following code:

```
struct SPerson
{ 
   string name; 
   string surname; 
   int age; 
}; 

priority_queue<SPerson, vector<SPerson>, FunkyFunctor> SuperPQ; 

// ** THIS IS THE BIT OF CODE WHICH I'M HAVING PROBLEM WITH

void InsertPerson(SuperPQ &kp, const char *name, const char *surname, int age) 
{ 
   SPerson newPerson; 
   newPerson.name = name; 
   newPerson.surname = surname; 
   newPerson.age = age; 

   kp.push(newPerson); 
 } 

int main(void)
{ 
    SuperPQ superQUEUE; 


    InsertPerson(superQUEUE, "Jeremy", "Clarkson", 54); 

 }
```

Why do I need pointers as function arguments in function called InsertPerson, why can't I use these variables instead of their pointers ?

Thank you in advance for politeness and any easy to understand explanation ;)

Cheers!

Comment: you could make it take `const std::string& name, const std::string& surname`

Answer (score 2):

A string literal, i.e. `"hello"` has type "array of *n* const char" (§ 2.14.5/8). In certain cases, arrays are said to [decay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying) to pointers to their first element. Therefore, `const char` would not be appropriate for taking an argument that expects a string literal. As mentioned by @Creris, because your data members are `std::string`s, you don't have to use `const char*`, and can replace them with `const std::string&` instead.

Answer (score 0):

An array has to be passed by pointer in C and C++. That's because function arguments are only single values and arrays and structs are multiple values.

So since a pointer is a single value it can be passed where multiple values cannot. It *points* to those structs or arrays.

On a machine code level this is because function calling conventions only have places in the register or stack for single values.